# Get verification object of release via GitHub API

Tags: github, github-api, signing

I want to get the `verification` object [(as it exist for commits)](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#the-verification-object) for a `release` object via the official GitHub API. I could not find anything about that in the [documentation for `release` objects](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/). Any Ideas?

(Just downloading the html release of the release page and reading the verification provided there does NOT work out for me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verification is only for commits, and tags (which are labels for commits).

A release is associated with a tag. Use Releases API to get the specific release and/or use the *tag_name* to lookup the commit which contains verification information.

Example steps:

1. GET /repos/:owner/:repo/releases/:release_id
2. GET /repos/:owner/:repo/commits/:tag_name (get *tag_name* from step 1).

If you know the *tag_name*, you can skip step 1.

The information you are looking for is in *commit.verification*.

Comment: The Git Tags api does not allow querying a tag by name instead by sha of the tag. Where am I supposed to get tjat sha from when I have only a release object?

Comment: Thanks for the note, @TobiasBrohl. I will amend my answer to include the exact steps required.

Comment: Thanks, I could follow your description until step to, but the sha in step 3 is not accepted `https://api.github.com/repos/TheMinefighter/StorageManagementTool/commits/1.1-b-1.0.1` is valid but `https://api.github.com/repos/TheMinefighter/StorageManagementTool/git/tags/ef31d88263e0326db8de361776520a392ef124da` not.

Comment: Hmm, you're right. Mystifying, perhaps it must be an annotated tag object? However, on the commits endpoint, you can access _commit.verification_ which has what you need. I'll change my answer again. :)

Comment: Ok, just wondering why the GitHub API Designers never thought of something like that.

Comment: Yeah, searching for a tag by _tag_name_ seems intuitive to me. :)